# Run powershell as admin by default from all shortcuts

Tags: powershell

I have two remote PC's that are being used to execute some powershell scripts, one is windows 7 and one is windows 10. Occasionally (if a reboot needs to happen) the scripts require admin privilege. On the windows 7 remote PC it always runs powershell as admin so it works fine. However on the remote windows 10 PC it does not, stopping the program from executing. What I need to know is how to get the remote windows 10 PC to run powershell as admin by default, anytime a powershell script is run.

I know this is possible because on a separate PC I've used powershell always opens in admin, but I've searched through the settings and can't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: How are you running the scripts?  Remote connections using `PsRemoting` requires the user to be a local admin by default.  Also, on Windows 7, there is no UAC (as with >=Vista) to prevent launching locally with full admin rights.

Comment: To be entirely honest I'm not sure how exactly the scripts are being run, it's not my code, I've been searching through the code trying to find it but no luck yet. what I do know is that if I can get powershell to always start as admin, then the problem goes away.

Comment: Look here for [a self elevating PowerShell script](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fully disable UAC by changing the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Value: "EnableLUA"

to 0, it will default run all programs (including powershell) as admin

Comment: Seems I got the Windows version for UAC wrong.  In any case, this would seem to be a big security risk as it applies to any app you might run, including malware.

Comment: @boxdog This is why you whitelist applications and disable the user-context from running scripts.  I'm not defending the practice, but it's not that uncommon to disable UAC.

Comment: I had the issue of powershell.exe not opening in elevated mode by default.  there were so many suggestions to get it working through making changes in the shortcut but this is what i needed.. this worked for me.. thanks.